# Yii2 file upload returns UPLOAD_ERR_PARTIAL

Tags: php, apache, yii, yii2, xampp

Images fail to upload when I create a new item but on updating the newly created item the file is successfully uploaded. Any reasons?
**Trending News Model**

```
class TrendingNews extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
    const EVENT_ADD_TRENDING_NEWS = 'add-trending-news';
      public $featuredFile;

      public function init() {
         $this->on(self::EVENT_ADD_TRENDING_NEWS, [$this, 'saveToLog']);
      }
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'trending_news';
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['headline_text','news_info', 'news_url', 'author', 'published', 'date_added', 'date_modified'], 'required'],
            [['headline_text', 'image_url', 'news_info', 'news_url'], 'string'],
            [['date_added', 'date_modified'], 'safe'],
            [['author'], 'string', 'max' => 20],
            [['published'], 'string', 'max' => 2],
            [['featuredFile'], 'file', 'skipOnEmpty' => false, 'extensions' => 'png, jpg'],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return [
            'id' => 'ID',
            'headline_text' => 'Headline',
            'image_url' => 'Image Url',
            'news_info' => 'Source',
            'news_url' => 'News Url',
            'author' => 'Author',
            'published' => 'Published',
            'date_added' => 'Date Added',
            'date_modified' => 'Date Modified',
            'featuredFile' => 'Featured Image',
        ];
    }

    public function uploadBanner()
    {
        if ($this->validate()) {
           $ymd = date("Ymd");
           $save_path = \Yii::getAlias('@backend') . '/web/uploads/' . $ymd . '/';
            if (!file_exists($save_path)) {
                mkdir($save_path, 0777, true);
            }
            $fileName = "trending_".Yii::$app->security->generateRandomString(20);
            $this->featuredFile->saveAs($save_path . $fileName .'.' . $this->featuredFile->extension);
            $this->image_url = $ymd . '/'. $fileName . '.' . $this->featuredFile->extension;
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public function upload()
    {
        if ($this->validate()) {
           $ymd = date("Ymd");
           $save_path = \Yii::getAlias('@backend') . '/web/uploads/' . $ymd . '/';
            if (!file_exists($save_path)) {
                mkdir($save_path, 0777, true);
            }

            $fileName = Yii::$app->security->generateRandomString(20);

            $this->featuredFile->saveAs($save_path . $fileName .'.' . $this->featuredFile->extension);
            $this->image_url = $ymd . '/'. $fileName . '.' . $this->featuredFile->extension;
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public function beforeSave($insert)
    {
        if (parent::beforeSave($insert)) {
            if ($this->isNewRecord) {
              $this->date_added = date("YmdHis");
              $this->author =   Yii::$app->user->identity->id;
            } 
            else {
               $this->date_modified = date("YmdHis"); 
            }
            return true;
        }
        else{
            return false;
        }
    }

    public function saveToLog($event)
    {
       //assigning attributes
       // echo 'mail sent to admin using the event';
       $app_log_model = new AppLog();
       $app_log_model->log_time = date("YmdHis");
       $app_log_model->log_activity = 'Added a trending news';
       $app_log_model->user_id = Yii::$app->user->identity->id;
       $app_log_model->device = "1";
       if ($app_log_model->save()) {
           return true;
       } else {
           return $app_log_model->getErrors() ;
       }
    }
}
```

**usage**

```
public function actionCreate()
{
    $model = new TrendingNews();

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
        $model->featuredFile = UploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'featuredFile');

        if(isset($model->featuredFile)){
            $model->upload();
            $model->save(false);
        } else {
            // file is uploaded successfully
            $model->save();
            //$model->trigger(BlogArticle::EVENT_EDIT_ARTICLE);
        }
        return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
    } else {
        return $this->render('create', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }
}
public function actionUpdate($id)
{
    $model = $this->findModel($id);

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
        $model->featuredFile = UploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'featuredFile');
        if(isset($model->featuredFile)){
            $model->upload();
            $model->save(false);
        } else {
            $model->save();
        }
        return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
    } else {
        return $this->render('update', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }
}
```

the app log shows this

```
$_FILES = [
    'TrendingNews' => [
        'name' => [
            'featuredFile' => 'another_evento.jpg'
        ]
        'type' => [
            'featuredFile' => ''
        ]
        'tmp_name' => [
            'featuredFile' => ''
        ]
        'error' => [
            'featuredFile' => 3
        ]
        'size' => [
            'featuredFile' => 0
        ]
    ]
]
```

`featuredFile` is not a database field
Is there something that is being done wrong?
I am using xampp,tried on a live server and the issue is same

Comment: you need to add the code for your model `TrendingNews` too. Is `featuredFile` a database field or a public attribute inside the model? and you said it works on an update where is the `update` function/action

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam I have updated the Model class

Comment: the file that you are uploading is required while saving a new record or not ? because your code in the model and the controller is confusing and contradicting

Comment: File is required on new record

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing it wrong if you have to require a file input on insert and not on the update you should add a scenario for it so that it asks you to provide file when adding a new record only.

Secondly you are using the same `ActiveRecord` model and added a custom attribute in it to be used as a file input and in the `upload()` function you are calling `validate()` and returning false if not validated but on the same time you are not checking for `true` or `false` in you controller action and on the very next line you are calling `$model->save(false)` with false so technically your script would never intimate the user if there is any validation error.

The file should be uploaded after the record is saved not before saving the record so that there are no extra files uploaded in case of error, although you want the file to be required on `insert` so technically if file is not uploaded the record should not be saved, and for this reason we have transactions for database insertions you should use a transaction block to save the rcord and the file along with it

You should only call the `validate()` method for file uploading if you have a separate `FormModel` for file uploading otherwise you should load the instance from the `UploadedFile` to the model field and call the `$model->save()` which will automatically validate the model before saving you should just check for the empty filename before uploading so that when you are updating any record and not submitting a file the previous file should be kept as is.

You need to update your validation rules to the following first

```
/**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['headline_text','news_info', 'news_url', 'author', 'published', 'date_added', 'date_modified'], 'required'],
            [['headline_text', 'image_url', 'news_info', 'news_url'], 'string'],
            [['date_added', 'date_modified'], 'safe'],
            [['author'], 'string', 'max' => 20],
            [['published'], 'string', 'max' => 2],
             [ [ 'featuredFile' ] , 'required' , 'on' => 'insert' ] ,
            [ [ 'featuredFile' ] , 'file' , 'extensions' => 'png, jpg' , 'maxSize' => 200000 , 'tooBig' => 'Limit is 500KB' ] ,
        ];
    }
```

Change the `upload()` function to the following

```
 public function upload( $ymd , $fileName ) {
        if ( $this->featuredFile !== null && $this->featuredFile->name !== '' ) {
            $save_path = \Yii::getAlias ( '@backend' ) . '/web/uploads/' . $ymd . '/';
            if ( !file_exists ( $save_path ) ) {
                mkdir ( $save_path , 0777 , true );
            }

            if ( !$this->featuredFile->saveAs ( $save_path . $fileName ) ) {
                $this->addError ( 'featuredFile' , 'File could not be uploaded' );
                throw new \Exception ( 'File upload error' );
            }
        }
    }
```

Then add another method inside your model to remove old file in case of new file uploaded on `update`

```
 public function unlinkOldFile( $filename ) {
        if ( $filename !== '' ) {
            $save_path = \Yii::getAlias ( '@backend' ) . '/web/uploads/' . $filename;
            unlink ( $save_path );
        }
    }
```

after that change your `create` and `update` actions to the following so that they use `transation` blocks for database operations

```
public function actionCreate() {
    $model = new TrendingNews(['scenario'=>'insert']);

    if ( $model->load ( Yii::$app->request->post () ) ) {

        $model->featuredFile = UploadedFile::getInstance ( $model , 'featuredFile' );

        if ( $model->featuredFile !== null ) {
            $ymd = date ( "Ymd" );
            $fileName = Yii::$app->security->generateRandomString ( 20 ) . '.' . $model->featuredFile->extension;
            $model->image_url = $ymd . '/' . $fileName;
        }


        $transaction = Yii::$app->db->beginTransaction ();

        try {
            if ( !$model->save () ) {
                throw new \Exception ( 'Error Occoured' );
            }

            $model->upload ( $ymd , $fileName );

            $transaction->commit ();

            return $this->redirect ( [ 'view' , 'id' => $model->id ] );
        } catch ( \Exception $ex ) {
            $transaction->rollBack ();
        }
    }
    return $this->render ( 'create' , [
        'model' => $model ,
        ] );
}

public function actionUpdate( $id ) {
    $model = $this->findModel ( $id );

    if ( $model->load ( Yii::$app->request->post () ) ) {
        $model->featuredFile = UploadedFile::getInstance ( $model , 'featuredFile' );

        //$oldFile = '';
        $oldFile = $model->image_url;

        if ( $model->featuredFile !== null ) {

            $ymd = date ( "Ymd" );

            $fileName = Yii::$app->security->generateRandomString ( 20 ) . '.' . $model->featuredFile->extension;

            $model->image_url = $ymd . '/' . $fileName;

        }

        $transaction = Yii::$app->db->beginTransaction ();

        try {
            if ( !$model->save () ) {
                throw new \Exception ( 'Model error' );
            }

            $model->upload ( $ymd , $fileName );

            $model->unlinkOldFile ( $oldFile );

            $transaction->commit ();
            return $this->redirect ( [ 'view' , 'id' => $model->id ] );
        } catch ( Exception $ex ) {
            $transaction->rollBack ();
        }
    }
    return $this->render ( 'update' , [
        'model' => $model ,
        ] );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your time @Muhammad . I still get the validation error on insert new record "Please upload a file"

Comment: ooops sorry for that, i missed setting the `scenario` for `insert` please see the revised `actionCreate` first line, and set the `scenario` like `$model = new TrendingNews(['scenario'=>'insert']);`, and tell me if it works